# Is there a way to annotate PDF files in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, pdf-annotations

I am using the NPM library `react-pdf` to render user uploaded PDF file in a HTML`<canvas>` tag.
I am curious how can I add some labels on the content in that pdf by editing the canvas or is there any way of editing the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries support displaying pdfs.

This (paid) supports editing and annotating:
https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/annotations/react/

but it is paid -,-